Node.js, SQL connection null
I am refactoring an old API using Node.js.
I have an issue about persisting the connection to the database. Here is my code for the connection (which is working) :
import { createConnection } from "mysql";

let connection;

(async () => {
  try {
    const customEnv = await import('custom-env');
    customEnv.env(process.env.NODE_ENV);

    connection = createConnection({
      host: process.env.HOST,
      port: process.env.PORT,
      user: process.env.DB_USER,
      password: process.env.PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DB
    });

    connection.connect(error => {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }
      console.log("Successfully connected to the database.");
    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to setup the database connection:", error);
  }
})();

export default connection;

However, when I want to call an endpoint, like this for example :
import sql from "../../config/db.js";

static getProductTypes(result) {
    sql.query(`SELECT * FROM product_type`, (sqlErr, sqlRes) => {
        // My return here
    });
}

sql appears to be undefined and I don't get why. Maybe because of the async/await in my connection creation ? Maybe there is also another better way to initialize and persist this connection ?
Also, I tried to not do it with async/await, but in this case, all my process.env variables was undefined too ...
Don't hesitate if you need more information.
Thank you very much !

Found it !
import mysql from "mysql";

const { env } = await import('custom-env');
env(process.env.NODE_ENV);

// Create a connection to the database
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.HOST,
  port: process.env.PORT,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB
});

// Open the MySQL connection
connection.connect(error => {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log("Successfully connected to the database.");
});

export default connection;

async code wasn't a good idea after all !
